# Creating route-based templated hrefs with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, url-template

Adding links to resource representations is really easy to do within a Web API controller.  Using the controller's `Url` property (which is of `UrlHelper` class) you can build the href of a link using route names, like this:

```
var href = Url.Link("RouteName", new { id = 123 });
```

The value of `href` is computed based on route configuration - in this case something like `http://example.org/api/products/123`.  This is great because I can adjust route configurations without having to update all the places hrefs are generated.  All links emitted conform to the new configurations.

But can this, or any similar route-based technique, be used to create **templated** hrefs?  For example, to create a link from some resource to an arbitrary product using HAL's `templated` link property:

```
"_links": {
  "self": {
    "href": "http://example.org/api/productfinder"
  },
  "product": {
    "href": "http://example.org/api/products/{productId}",
    "templated": true
  }  
}
```

(I don't really have a resource called productfinder - just a contrived example for this question).

I tried setting the `routeValues` parameter to a string of the template, e.g.

```
var href = Url.Link("RouteName", new { id = "{productId}" });
```

This produces a URL-encoded string: `http://example.org/api/products/%7BproductId%7D`.  I could use `.Replace`, but this approach fails for another reason.  If the route configuration has type constraints e.g. `{id:int}` then the href becomes null.

I tried passing null to `routeValues` hoping I could then just append the template portion.  `Link()` returned null, so `href` ended up being just the template portion.  Plus this wouldn't work for complex routes like `api/{this}/something/{that}{?q}`

So I'm stuck.  Can I use routes to generate templated hrefs?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it took me a while, but I've got something that works.  The trick is to lookup the `RouteTemplate` from the configuration's route table.  Each controller has a reference to the configuration.  From there it was pretty easy.

I created an extension class to `ApiController`.  In practice I will probably subclass `ApiController` but the idea is the same.  Also, I may return the `Uri` object instead of using `.ToString()`.

```
public static class ApiControllerExtensions
{
    public static string GetTemplatedHref(this ApiController controller, string routeName, string controllerName = "")
    {
        var routeTemplate = controller.Configuration.Routes[routeName].RouteTemplate;

        var baseUri = new Uri(controller.Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
        var templatedHref = new Uri(baseUri, routeTemplate).ToString();

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName) ? 
            templatedHref : 
            templatedHref.Replace("{controller}", controllerName.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Now, when inside a controller's method and I need a templated href I can do this:

```
var href = this.GetTemplatedHref("RouteName");
```

This works well with route attributes.  It also works for pre-configured routes, e.g.:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

So I can supply the controller name and get the templated href like this:

```
var href = this.GetTemplatedHref("DefaultApi", "product");
```

Again in practice I'll modify and tweak, e.g. add options for absolute/relative, etc.  But the core problem of getting templates using route names is now solved.